# Android toolbar ocupando todo espaço do layout

Tags: android

Estou tentando realizar a implementação de um Toolbar em minha aplicação Android, mas por algum motivo ele ocupa todo espaço da tela.
Gostaria de saber por que, já que estou usando a propriedade below no layout depois do toolbar.

***activity_main.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llLogotipo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgLogotipo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/dmufscar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/frmbotoes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llLogotipo"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnIniciarRFID"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="RFID" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPatrimonio"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/btnPatrimonio" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

***tool_bar.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em seu arquivo **toolbar.xml** , faça as seguintes alterações:

1. Troque a linha `android:layout_height="match_parent"` por

   ```
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ```
2. Adicione a seguinte linha:

   ```
   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
   ```

Comment: Joia amigo! Deu certinho